# Laravel, table doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel

В базе данных `land` есть таблицы `peoples` и `pages`.
Также есть модели `People` и `Page`.
**People.php**

```
class People extends Model
{
//    protected $table = 'peoples';
}
...
```

**Page.php**

```
class Page extends Model
{
    //
}
```

В контроллере пытаюсь показать все записи через модели `People` и `Page`,
**маршрут**

```
Route::get('/', ['as'=>'home','uses'=>'IndexController@show']);
```

**контроллер**

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function show() {
        $pages = Page::all();
        dump($pages);

        $people = People::all();
        dump($people);
    }
}
```

но записи из таблицы `pages` нормально отображаются с помощью dump, а записи из таблицы `peoples` не отображаются, выдаёт ошибку:
`Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'land.people' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from`people`)`

Если в модели `People` добавить `protected $table = 'peoples';` то ошибка пропадает, но хотелось-бы понять, из-за чего ошибка, две модели практически идентичны.
Почему в модели `people` появляется ошибка?

Comment: Как у вас называется таблица в БД?

Comment: @Mully, таблицы `peoples и pages`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так происходит, потому что правила создания таблиц и моделей в laravel следующие:

Модель - ед.ч
Таблица - мн.ч

Если углубиться в изучение англ языка и попытаться понять причину, то можно найти, что
Page - страница (ед.ч), Pages (мн.ч) - страницы (ларавель приводит page во мн.ч)
people - люди (мн.ч хотя по правилам должно быть ед.ч), а peoples - НАРОД (это не является множественным числом от слова people!).
В результате laravel оставляет people так как есть так как оно уже является мн.ч! и ищет `land.people` в Вашей БД. Слово person (ед.ч) - people (мн.ч) <- данное преобразование является верным!

Comment: Не успел :), но вы верно ответили.

Comment: @Mully ну, извиняйте! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
class People extends Model
{
//    protected $table = 'peoples';
}
```

По умолчанию в фреймворках предусмотрено, что если вы не указываете в экземпляре класса свойство, или метод, описывающий имя таблицы, которую использует данный класс - то автоматически берет имя таблицы равное названию класса, в вашем случае `people`. Из этого выходит что вы зря закомментировали строчку, т.к. она определяет с какой таблицей вам работать. Есть два варианта решения вашей проблемы:

1. Переименовать класс `People` в `Peoples` - плохое решение, т.к. лучше задавать названия моделей и соответсвующих таблиц в единственном числе
2. Переименовать название таблицы, вместо `peoples` в `people`

А если быть еще честнее, то `People` - это и есть "Люди", поэтому слова `Peoples` просто не существует :)